# What is the best way to clean axle components?

Tags: toyota, cleaning, grease, axle

I'm currently servicing (changing seals/gaskets, some cleaning and repainting some parts) my front axle on a Toyota Land Cruiser 87. I'm also putting new brake rotors/calipers/pads.

What is the best way to clean the inner axle components from all the old grease/oil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use [brake cleaner](http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/1/1/590981--brakleen-brake-parts-cleaner-by-crc-part-05089.html) for all metal parts, some of which could be related to actual brakes.  It's good for for anything from gears to axles, bearing races, rotors.

Comment: Great! After posting this I've chat with someone who was also suggesting brake cleaner. And I have some in the garage, thanks DXM!

Answer (score 2):

[ih8mud.com forums](http://forum.ih8mud.com/60-series-wagons/) is a ***great*** resource for land cruisers with an extremely loyal following - I own an 80 series and use it for reference and help for all kinds of maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, I've been a member prior to get my Land Cruiser. This wasn't a Land Cruiser specific question so that's why I posted here!